# Java: Variable is already defined in method main

Tags: java, sorting, if-statement, for-loop, compiler-errors

So I have been the following error every time I try to compile my .java file

"error: variable max is already defined in method main(String[])
                int max = j; "

And I haven't been able to figure out what is the issue or how to fix it. Been stuck at it for about 2 hours now. What I'm trying to ultimately do is enter one integer into my array and sorting the digits in that integer from least to greatest to provide context.

Here is the relevant part from my code:

```
   int[] wholeNumber = new int[1];


   //Sorting algorithm beginning
   int n = wholeNumber.length;

   System.out.println("Length of array is :" + n); //Array length displayed

   for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
   {
     System.out.println("Hello!");

     int max = i;

     for(int j = i+1; j < 1; j++)
     {
       if (wholeNumber[j] > wholeNumber[max])
       {  
          int max = j;
       }

     }
     if (max != i)
     {
        wholeNumber[i] = wholeNumber[max];
        wholeNumber[max] = wholeNumber[i];
     }



   }
   //Sorting algorithm end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you have `int max` declared twice. You need to change the second one to a variable *assignment*, not *declaration*:

```
 int max = i;

 for(int j = i+1; j < 1; j++)
 {
   if (wholeNumber[j] > wholeNumber[max])
   {  
      max = j; // NOT: int max = j;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare `int max` once at the highest scope you require it.  Remove the `int` keyword from inside of your `if` statement; this will turn it into an assignment statement instead of a declaration statement.

As an aside, this statement is pointless:

```
if (max != i)  {
   wholeNumber[i] = wholeNumber[max];
   wholeNumber[max] = wholeNumber[i];
}
```

`wholeNumber[i]` will be set to whatever is in `wholeNumber[max]`, which you then attempt to set right back into `wholeNumber[max]`.  You were probably going for a swap, which would require (in this case) a third variable:

```
if (max != i)  {
   int swp = wholeNumber[i];
   wholeNumber[i] = wholeNumber[max];
   wholeNumber[max] = swp;
}
```

Comment: Yes I was going for a swap, thank you for your help!